# "Operation note permitted" when trying to change kern.sysv.shmmni on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, unix, kernel, shared-memory

I would like to change the shmmni parameter of my shared memory kernel settings, but when I try to write to it, I get "Operation not permitted".

```
sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmmni=2048
```

Output:

```
kern.sysv.shmmni: 64
sysctl: kern.sysv.shmmni=2048: Operation not permitted
```

Can this be circumvented in any way? Why is the operation not permitted? shmmni should be a writable parameter... I can set the other shared memory params (shmmax, shmmin, shmall, shmseg)

I can change shmmni by updating /etc/sysctl.conf or by changing the setting via a launchdaemon, but these changes only have effect upon rebooting the system.

I would like to force-set it without rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this specific entry is protected by SIP.
Not sure you're willing to do that, but if you [disable SIP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection), you can then use `sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmmni=2048`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue setting other kernel parms in OSX Sierra.

Once I sudo su - root, I was able to execute successfully.